# Any surface is locally a level surface

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that any surface is locally a level surface. I know that a surface is locally the graph of a function and I suppose it has to be used, as well as the implicit function theorem (because I have been reading other proofs also about this and it is always used). The problem is that I'm not getting how to use any of this. Can someone give me a hint, please?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggestion.
Suppose that $\mathbf{p}$ is a point in surface $\mathbb{P}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Then there is a small open neighborhood $U_p\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ around $\mathbf{p}$, a small neighborhood $B_0\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ of zero, and a smooth function $\phi:B_0\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $U_x\cap \mathbb{P}=\{(\mathbf{x},\phi(\mathbf{x})):\mathbf{x}\in B_0\}$. That is, around $p$ the surface is the graph of a function. Let

$$ H(x,y,z)=\phi(x,y)-z$$
Then for any $\mathbf{q}\in U_p\cap\mathbb{P}$, $H(\mathbf{q})=0$. The implicit function theorem should then provide the conclusion to the problem.